# smoothness and symmetry imply smoothness in two variables

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, differential-geometry

Suppose that a function  $f:\mathbb C\times\mathbb C\to \mathbb R$ has the following properties:

- $f$ is symmetric; which means $f(x,y)=f(y,x)$
- For any $x\in \mathbb C$, the map $f(x,\cdot):\mathbb C\to\mathbb R$ is $C^\infty$.

Is it true that $f$ is a $C^\infty$ function on $\mathbb C\times\mathbb C$?

Comment: Maybe this is helpful https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartogs%27_theorem the english version of this page is a little bit short =\

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Counterexample:
$$
f(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{\operatorname{Re} (xy)}{|x|^2 + |y|^2}, &(x,y)\ne(0,0),\\[2ex]
0, &(x,y)=(0,0).
\end{cases}
$$
This function is not even continuous at $(0,0)$.

Comment: this function doesn't map into $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @NathanaelSkrepek: Oh, sorry, I missed that part of the question. Will edit.